# Accessing winform's webbrowser control from another winform, from different assemblies

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one winform

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string address = textBox1.Text;
            webBrowser1.Navigate(address);
        }
    }
```

It just loads the webpage, taking the url from textbox.
And that is the end of the project.

Later i have another winform, which will traverse the dom of first winform's webBrowser control and list all the tags. **Both winforms are in different assemblies**.
I know how to do it using mshtml when both are in same assembly.
But in this case how do i start?

I only have the exe file of first winform, no source code.

Comment: is webBrowser1 property in the winform is public? Try to make it public then access it via Form1.webBrowser1 .........

Comment: as i said i dont have first winform's source code. I have only the exe.

Comment: That's the end of this project.

Comment: have you tried Reflector to disassemble code?

Comment: yes! but i was looking for win32 function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by different assemblies you mean different projects, or one project and one assembly, then one project should reference the assembly/other project. That way you'll be able to use the class of the form that contains the Web Browser control.

In order to use the web browser control via its containing form, you'll need:

- the control to be public, or...
- a public property to access it via a `get` accessor, or...
- failing the above, you can still use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx).

Comment: Two different projects! Actually, I have the first winform's exe only, no source. So basically it has to be treated as one application, which i have to access through winform

Comment: The .exe file of a .NET application is basically a DLL that's capable of starting a program contained in it. You can reference it as though it were a DLL just fine.

Comment: Create an instance of the form. The browser will be a member of the form. If the control is not public and the form doesn't have a `get` accessor for it, you'll need to use reflection.